# Active Directory Removal Created new user folder for administrator. How to revert?

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller

I set up Active Directory Domain Service a couple of days ago thinking it would be neat to toy around with, upon realizing that I have no need for it I removed it from my roles and features.

Upon restart I was booted into a newly created user around with a users folder named "Administrator.SERVERNAME"

The old administrator folder is still in the C:/users folder.

How to I modify the administrator account to use the old Administrator user folder.

Answer (score 0):

1. First to stay safe - If you do not have another administrator account to use, then create a new temporary administrator account, log off from your SERVERNAME\Administrator acc and log in with SERVERNAME\TEMPADMIN account
2. Rename "C:USERS\Administrator.SERVERNAME" user profile folder to something else, like: "C:USERS\Administrator.NEW" and after that rename your old admin user account folder name "C:USERS\Administrator" into the  -> "C:USERS\Administrator.SERVERNAME"

Make sure that your SERVERNAME\Administrator (new admin) acc has full access rights to your old administrator user profile folder which is now named "C:USERS\Administrator.SERVERNAME"

Test your settings, and if everything is ok, you can ditch the newly created TEMPADMIN acc and do the cleanup. Test everything.

Bonus - location to the **ProfileImagePath** registry key:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\SID(SID of your user profile